How can I securely distribute an enterprise WPF app in 2024?
We have an enterprise Windows desktop application written in WPF, based on net8. It is used on PCs which are at times offline and have only a mobile data connection to the internet. The app receives updates every now and then.
I want to create a user friendly and IT-admin friendly installation/update experience. Ideally, IT-admin never has to do anything. Users are not IT people but Windows literate.
The installation and update go over the internet - which leads us to securing the installation/update process. We have a pre-existing agreement with DigiCert, and I have also looked at Azure Trusted Signing.
ClickOnce
Works fairly well until you get to the price. Trusted Signing does not support signing of the ClickOnce manifests, so we’re stuck with DigiCert - which is pretty expensive (~3_000 USD per 10_000 signatures). (Given our process, we need on the order of 500 signatures a month.)
Note that Trusted Signing gives you 5_000 signatures for 10 USD a month.
MSIX
Trusted Signing supports MSIX. However, most organizations have disabled ms-appinstaller (why). ms-appinstaller manages the auto-updates and differential updates, and so you have to check for updates manually and download the entire MSIX package. On top of that, MSIX package always includes the runtime as framework-dependent packaging is not implemented which in our case is problematic (limited bandwidth).
Squirrel.Windows
Does not support .net8
Conclusion
Any chance there is an error in my above reasoning or discovery? Any other options?
As otherwise it appears we are stuck with ClickOnce and an expensive sign provider.

Have you looked at Velopack, which grew out of Clowd.Squirrel, which was an updated version of Squirrel.Windows?

Thanks @RichardDeeming, Velopack has worked out very well for us. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it?

Have you considered creating an MSI that installs with basic UI? You can create one using open-source tools like Wix Toolset or paid tools like Advanced Installer.
Some paid tools, for example, the Enterprise edition of Advanced Installer, provide built-in auto-updater tools to handle silent update of new versions. This tool is expensive too, but at least you can purchase a perpetual license (future updates/maintenance are optional) and in the end it will cost you much less than the annual DigiCert subscription.
If you choose to go the OSS route, you can try integrating the Omaha updater into your Wix Toolset package.
https://github.com/google/omaha
Disclaimer: I work on the team building Advanced Installer.
